# How do you get the current date and time in emscripten c++

Tags: c++, time, emscripten

I need to get the current date and time in my emscripten code. I know there is emscripten_date_now(). But how would I get the day, the month, the year, and the time (hrs, minutes, and seconds) from that? (Or should I use the C/C++ time functions?).

Some operations that I need to perform is to be able to add a week. To change the month and year.

I am really stuck on this, so help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you get the current date and time in emscripten c++

Use [std::chrono::system_clock::now()](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) to get the current point in time.

> how would I get the day, the month, the year, and the time (hrs, minutes, and seconds)

With the date library [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)

```cpp
#include <date/date.h>
#include <iostream>

int
main ()
{
  using namespace date;
  auto const currentTimePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::now ();
  auto const currentDate = year_month_day{ floor<days> (currentTimePoint) };
  std::cout << "year: " << currentDate.year () << std::endl;
  std::cout << "month: " << currentDate.month () << std::endl;
  std::cout << "day: " << currentDate.day () << std::endl;
  auto const timeWithOutDate = make_time (currentTimePoint - date::floor<days> (currentTimePoint));
  std::cout << "hour: " << timeWithOutDate.hours () << std::endl;
  std::cout << "minute: " << timeWithOutDate.minutes () << std::endl;
  std::cout << "second: " << timeWithOutDate.seconds () << std::endl;
}
```

Example output:

```
year: 2022
month: Jan
day: 24
hour: 11h
minute: 34min
second: 18s
```

> Some operations that I need to perform is to be able to add a week

```cpp
#include <date/date.h>
#include <iostream>

int
main ()
{
  using namespace date;
  auto now = floor<days> (std::chrono::system_clock::now ());
  std::cout << "now in 1 week: " << now + weeks{ 1 } << std::endl;
}
```

Example output:

```
now in 1 week: 2022-01-31
```